# How do I add a large folder to git add in several parts?

Tags: git, directory, gitlab, push

I have my **folders/**, it have ~*100.000 files*, and it weighs about *2 Gio*.

When i want `git add folders/`, no problem but when i want `git push`, my git service disconnects at about 50%.

**The files are unique**, I can't re-generate them so I save them via Git which I think is great, but that's not the point :P

**My question :** Is there a solution to **push** a folder with such a large amount of data without any problem?

Comment: `git add folders/a*` - add all files starting with name `a`. then `git add folders/b*`. etc.

Comment: It can indeed be tempting :) thank you ! So how can I delete the folder I added previously ? because it's really too heavy.

Comment: `git reset` is used to unstage added files and to reset to previous commits.

Comment: Ok, i have try, all is good, thanks you for this tip :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this https://git-lfs.github.com/
There are some limitations to the file size in git (max 100 mb files, max 10GB repo size), git lfs allows to have bigger files than 100mb.